How do I make separate api calls for different sheets (that are from one spreadsheet)?
I am trying to integrate google sheets api with nodejs. I am wondering what the correct syntax is for calling two different sheets, separately (note that they are inside one spreadsheet). I tried asking chatgpt and gemini regarding this and I think they gave out to different answers, which adds more confusion. I'll add them here too, please tell me which of them is correct, or if none, I hope someone could help me with this.
The video tutorials and google sheet api library that I have encountered only uses one sheet as an example, so I am unsure of how exactly I should do this. Also, what I expect is that whenever I use the api call for Sheet1, of course only that sheet will be updated, my main goal is to not make those calls interfere with my other sheet.
edit: oh, i just saw the rule abt the use of ai now, but i am not sure if this is inside that scope (is it?). anyways, i'll remove the AIs' code now, hope someone can share me the correct syntax for this case instead. thanks a lot :))

code from: jrgrimshaw (https://github.com/jrgrimshaw/google-sheets-node/blob/master/index.js)
const getRows = await googleSheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
    auth,
    spreadsheetId,
    **range: "Sheet1!A:A",** //this is what I want to edit specifically, I want to know how to set a range if i have two sheets to call
  });

  // Write row(s) to spreadsheet
  await googleSheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
    auth,
    spreadsheetId,
    **range: "Sheet1!A:B",**
    valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED",
    resource: {
      values: [[request, name]],
    },
  });


I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the correct syntax is for calling two different sheets, separately (note that they are inside one spreadsheet). Can I ask you about the details of your current issue and your expected result? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Hi! I need to call for CRUD operations on my program. My data are grouped into two different tables, and each table are in separate worksheets (Sheet1, Sheet2). There are times when I only need to perform operations with the data on one of the sheet, but I can't find the exact syntax for setting the calls for more than 1 worksheet. I will add the picture above of what I am referring to as different sheets, as well as the code that I have been using as reference for this. Thank you.

Thank you for replying. From your reply, by guessing your expected answer, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your expected answer, I apologize.

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected answer, how about the following sample scripts? In these sample scripts, the values are retrieved from multiple ranges by one API call. And, the values are put into multiple ranges by one API call.
Sample 1
In this sample, Method: spreadsheets.values.batchGet is used. This sample script retrieves values from 2 ranges like "'Sheet1'!A:A", "'Sheet2'!A:A".
const sheets = google.sheets({ version: "v4", auth }); // Please set your client.
const spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set your Spreadsheet ID.

const ranges = ["'Sheet1'!A:A", "'Sheet2'!A:A"]; // Please set your ranges.

const { data: { valueRanges } } = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchGet({ spreadsheetId, ranges});
console.log(valueRanges);


When this script is run, the values are retrieved from "'Sheet1'!A:A", "'Sheet2'!A:A" by one API call. You can confirm the retrieved values from valueRanges.

Sample 2
In this sample, Method: spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate is used. This sample script puts 2 values to 2 ranges like "'Sheet1'!A1", "'Sheet2'!A1".
const sheets = google.sheets({ version: "v4", auth }); // Please set your client.
const spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set your Spreadsheet ID.

// Please set your ranges and values.
const data = [
  { values: [["sample1", "sample2"]], range: "'Sheet1'!A1" },
  { values: [["sample3", "sample4"]], range: "'Sheet2'!A1" },
];

const res = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate({ spreadsheetId, requestBody: { valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED", data } });
console.log(res.data);


When this script is run, the values [["sample1", "sample2"]] and [["sample3", "sample4"]] are put from "'Sheet1'!A1" and `"'Sheet2'!A1" by one API call.

References:

Method: spreadsheets.values.batchGet
Method: spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate


@meue1004 Did my answer show you the result that you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue as you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. If you have issues with my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.
